# Installing Windows 8.1 on Ubuntu 14.10 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, 14.10

I want to ask if it is possible to **install Windows 8.1 on a Ubuntu machine** making it dual boot ?

**If yes**, please also tell the **procedure**.

**If no**, please tell any **workaround** for installing latest **high end graphics windows games** on Ubuntu machine. (They do not work in virtualbox and wine).

I searched very much on Internet but can not find any satisfactory solution.
Please help.

Comment: I want to install Windows on Ubuntu machine, not the other way around. Both of these questions are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to give three links in one answer, so I split my answer up.

Windows wipes out any and all bootloaders except for its own, so to dual boot you have reinstall grub yourself.

The easiest way bf doing so is using 
[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from Ubuntu Live CD/USB. If you have full Ubuntu installation CD/USB, it is "Try Ubuntu" option.

I did so myself and it worked.

Comment: So please could you tell me the exact procedure of what steps you followed.

Comment: I am sorry, I had to go.

Comment: First I entered live session by choosing "try Ubuntu" during Ubuntu instalation proccess. Then I opened terminal by pressing `ctrl+alt+t` and entered following commands there:`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair` `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair` `sudo boot-repair`. Pressed big bad button `Reccomended repair`. Waited for it to finish.Rebooted.??? Profit. Side effect: grub window became black, you can change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Well..you got to create a partition for Windows (how much would you like? 100GB?) for that there are some tools you can use, but I like to do that on the Windows 8 installation.

Before you start it, I recommend you to make a backup of your files, just in case.

If you don't know how to do it:
1)Insert the CD/USB with the Windows installation files
2)Restart the computer (you might need to press f12 if it doesn't boot from cd and select it manually)
3)Follow the instructions and choose to administrate partitions
4)Create a partition where your ubuntu is installed (if you dint know which one is, it should be the bigger one ;) )
5) Choose the size of the partition you want
6) There must now be a new partition called Unallocated Space. Thats where you are going to put it.
7) select it and click next
8) there you go! :D (I recommend you to use Custom installation if you don't know what are you going to do)

If something bad happens, don't worry. You can always try to install it again.

Comment: But I read here http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2212502/install-windows-ubuntu-linux.html that you have to install Ubuntu Boot loader after windows has been installed. Can you please elaborate on this thing?

Comment: this if you have windows already installed.. my advice: backup your data, create an ubuntu usb with Startup Disk Creator, install windows 8 on your pc (deleting all partitions you have) and then choose to install ubuntu along windows

Comment: but I don't want to remove Ubuntu as it will delete all my files.

Comment: So just do as I said: find a way to free some space for windows 8 and on the Windows 8 installation proccess, install it on where it says 'Free/Available Space'

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Article for Sane People](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2025909/gaming-on-linux-a-guide-for-sane-people-with-limited-patience.html) and [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/), although I only played League of Legends using the latter.

Comment: But PlayOnLinux only plays certain games which are 3-4 years old. I wanna play latest one ,which I do not think it currently supports.